# Is it possible to pass a non-enum value as an enum function parameter?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, enums, reinterpret-cast

I have a function that looks like this:

```
std::string SomeClass::convertStateToString(StateE state) const
{
  std::string stateAsString;
  switch (state)
  {
    case UNKNOWN:
      stateAsString = "UNKNOWN";
      break;
    case OFFLINE:
      stateAsString = "OFFLINE";
      break;
    case ENABLED:
      stateAsString = "ENABLED";
      break;
    case DISABLED:
      stateAsString = "DISABLED";
      break;
    default:
      stateAsString = "ABNORMAL";
      break;
  }
  return stateAsString;
}
```

Where StateE is defined as:

```
typedef enum
{
  UNKNOWN      = 0,
  OFFLINE      = 1,
  ENABLED      = 2,
  DISABLED     = 3
} StateE;
```

For unit testing purposes i want to feed some bad data to `convertStateToString` and verify that i get `"ABNORMAL"` back. Is this possible?

In other words, is it possible to pass a value outside the range of an enum as an in-parameter to a function where the signature of the function says the parameter is of the enum type?

After having experimented with pointers and `reinterpret_cast`, i'm almost ready to claim that the function `convertStateToString` can not under any circumstances return `"ABNORMAL"`.

No method is too hackish!

Comment: Seams like you want strongly typed enums: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this in your unit test :

```
convertStateToString(static_cast<StateE>(10));
```

This will force your code to pass in the "default" of your switch/case.

Comment: Yes, static_cast works, reinterpret_cast doesn't. I feel a bit stupid now :)

Answer (score 1):

No matter in how many ways C++ tries to enforce proper type checking,
it should still be possible to just take the address of a memory location and change its content.
Ex: declare a variable of type StateE, get its address, write in it a value that is out of range, then pass it to the function.
Probably the variable should be volatile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem:

```
std::string convertStateToString(StateE state);

int main() {
    std::cout << convertStateToString(StateE(30)) << "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
ABNORMAL
```

Comment: Yes it turns out reinterpret_cast was the problem